# Remove dollar sign only from integer values not form starting with strings

Tags: php, regex

Below is my string and I want to remove $ only from integers and float values and don't want to remove $ from string like "Mastsdsdosmsy $4.50 AsI" Please can any one help me.

```
 $string = ' "2016-02-19","Videomssdsdsize",
 "Mastsdsdosmsy $4.50 AsI","","Masdsdtomy 
 $2.00  In-App","27753492","171352","155928",
 "109608","0.62","91.00","70.29","$2.25",
 "$246.62","$219.22","$27.40","11.11","32",
 "0.03","78937","72.02"';
```

I am already using below regular expression to remove $ but it's removeing from string as well but I don't want to remove $ from string as I mentioned above string
Thanks

```
$result=str_replace('$','' , $string);
```

Comment: exactly how is `$4.50` NOT a float value? why is $2.00 ok but not $4.50? **ALL** of your values are strings, so by your requirements, **NONE** of those values should be modified.

Comment: It's working fine for $2.00 and $4.50 but its also removing $ form string as a I mentioned it's removing $ from this string""Mastsdsdosmsy $4.50 AsI"" and I don't want to remove it from string

Comment: ALL of your values are "strings".

Comment: Marc B you're being unhelpful
Fiaz your string is a string of information, representing strings "string", integers 123 and floats 123.234

Comment: @Marc Yes all of values are string

Comment: You can skip quoted parts that contain an alpha and match dollar if there is a boundary (which can only be to a digit) with optional space ahead: [`(?i)"[^"]*?[A-Z][^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\$\h?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wS6eK5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
$result=preg_replace('/"\$(\d)/','"$1' , $string);
```

I haven't tested this solution. The approach is to use a regular expression to match every `$` character followed by a number and replace it wit an empty string.

**Edit**:
I've edited the regexp to match and capture the numbers after the `$` sign and to replace the whole match just with the matched number

**Edit 2**:
I've edited the regex to do the replace only when the `$` sign is after a `"`

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained what the regular expression is doing. If he just uses your regular expression he will learn nothing at all

Comment: This is not a solution anyway.

Comment: @tudor it's not working it's removing $4 form string and display .50

Comment: @FiazAhmad. I've modified the line and tested it. It looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your search string in delimiters first so

```
preg_replace('/ /',...
```

or

```
preg_replace('! !',...
```

so

```
$result=preg_replace('/"\$/','"', $string);
```

What this is doing:

Search for a speach mark "

then a dollar sign \$ (escaped or it would be searching for an end of line)

And replacing that with "

Comment: Thanks it's working for me $result=preg_replace('/"\$/','', $string);

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answered, helps the community

Comment: unfortunately it's giving little bit issue on floating values it's removing $ sign but adding double quotation " at the end of floating value like 14.50"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex replacement:

```
'~"\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?")~'
```

And replace with `"$1`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL6yB6/1)

This regex will match:

- `"\$` - a `"` followed with a literal `$` symbol
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?")` - Group 1 matching:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional group (one or zero occurrences) matching a literal dot followed by one or more digits
  - `"` - a double quote